Folder approval in power automate flow
The aim of my flow is to limit the creation of folders to selected users only.  I am exploring the use of when an item is created properties only and a condition to state isfolder equals true.  I then wonder if a further condition in the true parameter for created by can be defined.  False triggering a delete file command.
But this appears to be a very long winded approach to a simple command and I wonder if there is a simpler and more logical approach I have missed?
Any help welcomed.
I have explored various in built templates and manual trigger builds, but without success.
See flow example

not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide an example?

"But this appears to be a very long winded approach": welcome in the world of PowerAutomate ;) .

I have added a flow example to help identify the method I had started.  But I am sure there must be an easier way for such a basic command.  Limit folder creation to specified users in sharepoint online library?  I have removed the add folder command in library settings, but library sync is in place with OneDrive, so need a further level of control.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
